# How is the potential energy of a satellite/planet in orbit derived?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, potential-energy, orbital-motion, satellites

Recall that for a Hookian spring:

$F(r) = -kr$ (force vector and radius vector point in opposite directions, hence the negative sign)

Since negative work is a positive change in potential energy,

$$U(r) = -\int F(r)dr
=-\int -kr dr
=kr^2/2 \tag1$$

Newton's Universal Law of Gravitation states that:

$$F_g = \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}\tag2$$

And this is where I'm confused. Since the force vector and radius vector point in opposite directions, I thought you should throw in a negative sign:

$$F_g = -\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}\tag3$$

$$U(r) = -\int F(r)dr = -\int - \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}dr\tag4$$

$$=\int \frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}dr\tag5$$

$$= -\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r}\tag6$$

Which is clearly wrong. The force vector and radius vector point in opposite directions, so why shouldn't there be a negative sign?

Comment: Your expression is correct though? gravitational potential energy is always negative Although your derivation is missing some very key ideas such as the dot product between a path in sperical coordinates, and the actual r unit vector. The bounds of the integral

Comment: Related:https://en.wikipedia.org//wiki/Potential_energy#Derivation , also your equation 2 is wrong and 3 is correct

Comment: Related, [Contradiction on gravitational potential energy](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360281/contradiction-on-gravitational-potential-energy/360334#360334) relating to the the sign of $F_{\rm g}$ and $dr$.

Answer (score 0):

$$U = -\int_{\infty}^{\vec{r}} \vec{F}_{g} \cdot \vec{dr}$$

$$\vec{F}_{g} =-\frac{GMm}{r^2}\hat r$$

$$\vec{dr} = dr  \hat r + rd\theta \hat \theta + r\sin(\theta)d\phi \hat \phi$$

This reduces then, to:

$$U= \int_{\infty}^{r} \frac{GMm}{r^2} dr $$

$$ U(r) = -\frac{GMm}{r} \biggr\rvert_{\infty}^{r} = -\frac{GMm}{r}$$